# Target the first child in a parent that doesn't have a specific class

Tags: css, css-selectors

The title is a mouthful but that's precisely what I'm trying to accomplish.  I need to target the first instance where a class is not present - in this case I'm trying to hide the span in #3. This needs to be dynamic though as it won't always be #3. I tried getting sneaky with `:not` and `:nth-of-type` but its horribly wrong.

```
 <style>
   li:not(.done):nth-of-type(1).span.divider {display:none}
 </style>

 <-- 1 -->
 <li class="wrapper done"><span class="divider"></span></li>
 <-- 2 -->
 <li class="wrapper done"><span class="divider"></span></li>
 <-- 3 - hide this span -->
 <li class="wrapper"><span class="divider"></span></li>
 <-- 4 -->
 <li class="wrapper"><span class="divider"></span></li>
 <-- 5 -->
 <li class="wrapper"><span class="divider"></span></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to use two selectors for this:

```css
/*hide all the element after .done selector without done*/
li.done ~ li:not(.done) {
  display:none;
}

/*show all the element after the first one without .done*/
li.done ~ li:not(.done) ~ li {
  display:list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <!-- 1 -->
  <li class="wrapper done"><span class="divider">1</span></li>
  <!-- 2 -->
  <li class="wrapper done"><span class="divider">2</span></li>
  <!-- 3 - hide this span -->
  <li class="wrapper"><span class="divider">3</span></li>
  <!-- 4 -->
  <li class="wrapper"><span class="divider">4</span></li>
  <!-- 5 -->
  <li class="wrapper"><span class="divider">5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always going to be after an element with the class .done then this should work: `li.done + li:not(.done) .divider { display:none; }`

Answer (score 0):

My approach to the problem would be to use two separate rules; one to style *all* the elements lacking the given class-name and another to override all elements lacking the given class-name that follow an element lacking that class-name:

```
/* Selects all <li> elements with the 'wrapper'
   class-name that does not have the 'done' class: */
li.wrapper:not(.done) {
  color: limegreen;
}

/* Selects all elements, as above, that follow an
   element without the 'done' class-name; effectively
   we style the first occurrence using the above rule
   because the first occurrence - obviously - cannot
   be a general (later) sibling of a matching element: */
li.wrapper:not(.done)~li.wrapper:not(.done) {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 95vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  height: 10vh;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

li.wrapper:not(.done) {
  color: limegreen;
}

li.wrapper:not(.done)~li.wrapper:not(.done) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="wrapper done">&lt;li&gt;: 1</li>
  <li class="wrapper done">&lt;li&gt;: 2</li>
  <li class="wrapper done">&lt;li&gt;: 3</li>
  <li class="wrapper">&lt;li&gt;: 4</li>
  <li class="wrapper">&lt;li&gt;: 5</li>
  <li class="wrapper">&lt;li&gt;: 6</li>
  <li class="wrapper">&lt;li&gt;: 7</li>
  <li class="wrapper">&lt;li&gt;: 8</li>
  <li class="wrapper">&lt;li&gt;: 9</li>
  <li class="wrapper">&lt;li&gt;: 10</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [Negation (`:not()`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
- [General sibling (`~`) combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).